# How to make Cordova Media capture not save to gallery

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, storage, media

I am trying to use [Cordova Media Capture](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-media-capture/#capturecapturevideo) to take short video clips with my app.  Since these videos are short I don't want to save them on the users phone. The API doesn't seem to specify an option to do this either.  How would I implement something like this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **cordovaFileTransfer** plugin to send captured video files to your preferred location.

```
$scope.captureVideo = function() {
    var options = { limit: 3, duration: 15 };

        $cordovaCapture.captureVideo(options).then(function(videoData) {
        // Success! Video data is here
        /** following is sample usage to upload the video to server.**/
                    path = videoData[0].localURL;
                    var options = new FileUploadOptions();
                    options.fileKey = "uploadfile";                
                    options.fileName = videoData[0].name;
                    options.mimeType = "video/mp4";
         $cordovaFileTransfer.upload("video-upload-url", path, options).then(function (result) {

                //Success! Video file uploaded to destination.

                    }, function (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                    },                 
                    function (progress) {
                        if (progress.lengthComputable) {
                        } else {}
                    });
        }, function(err) {
        // An error occurred. Show a message to the user
        });   }
```

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-media-capture/

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file-transfer/index.html